# Is it possible to implement a pseudo-anonymous login using a signed bitcoin transaction as proof of payment?

Tags: authentication, bitcoin, bitcoind, blockchain

I think something like this is possible, but I'm a little fuzzy on the details.  As I understand it:

- I have one or more bitcoin addresses
- Users send bits to that address
- Users can log into my app by providing proof that they control the address that sent (a sufficient number of) bits to my address

What I'm not clear on is how the proof part works.  How do users generate that proof, and what do I do to validate it?

Also, do I have to keep a full copy of the blockchain on my server to do this, or are there APIs available?

Thanks!

Comment: first it's not necessarily a good idea (imagine if SO was using Bitcoin as a login system: the blockchain would contain a *lot* of tiny transactions).  But you may be very interested in this: someone very recently (yesterday as I write this comment) posted a blog entry *and* full open-source code about a system allowing to rent virtual instances per hour (pseudo-)anonymously using Bitcoin.  Here's the link: https://www.stackmonkey.com/blog/for-bitcoin-from-a-twitter-marketing-bot/
  I hope it helps you!

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to implement a pseudo-anonymous login system using a signed bitcoin transaction as proof of payment. The basic idea is that users can prove that they control a specific bitcoin address by signing a message with the private key associated with that address.

To do this, users would need to have a bitcoin wallet that allows them to sign messages. They would then sign a message with their private key and provide the signed message and the address it was signed with as proof.

On your end, you would need to have a way to validate the signed message. This can be done by using a bitcoin library or API that allows you to verify the signature and check that it was signed with the correct private key associated with the address provided.

You would not necessarily need to keep a full copy of the blockchain on your server, but you would need access to the blockchain data to verify the transactions and confirm that the user has sent a sufficient number of bitcoins to your address. This can be done through various bitcoin libraries or APIs that provide access to blockchain data without the need to run a full node.